# Pump defective?

Tags: pump

When I started pumping a new Pumpico floor pump, the shaft slid down doing nothing for about 12 pumps and then kicked in for 2 hard pumps before it did nothing again for another 10 pumps. It's a schrader valve. My tires needed only a little air. Do I have a defective pump?

When I pump the shaft when it's not connected I feel no air coming out of the tube.  Is that normal?

Answer (score 7):

That sounds like a broken seal in the pump.

I had to google the brand as I'd never heard of it before. There are a few amazon reviews that also state the pump didn't work on arrival.
[Link to Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FCVWR29)

Given that evidence, and the tragedy that is the Pumpico website:
https://thepumpico.com/ I'd suggest returning the pump and buying something from an established manufacturer of cycling products/accessories.

Comment: +1 for "buying something from an established manufacturer of cycling products/accessories"

Comment: +1 for the website's template text still showing